# Page using Theme.of(context) gets rebuilt many times Problem

Tags: flutter, mobx

I use Mobx State management in my Flutter Project. My aim is to change the theme of the application to light & dark when I press the "press me" TextButton on the AppBar. But the widgets I use Theme.of(context) are rebuilt many times (about 10 times). How can I avoid this? Thank you in advance

main.dart

```
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

final ThemeState _themeState = ThemeState();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint("MyApp build");

    return Observer(
      name: "MyApp",
      builder: (_) {
        return MaterialApp.router(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: _themeState.theme,
          routerConfig: NavigatorRoutes().router,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return const Root();
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class Root extends StatefulWidget {
  const Root({super.key});

  @override
  State<Root> createState() => _RootState();
}

class _RootState extends State<Root> {
  final RootStateManager rootStateManager = RootStateManager();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint("Root build");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: InkWell(
          child: const Text("go sample"),
          onTap: () => NavigatorManager.instance.go(
            context,
            route: NavigateRoutes.sample.withParaph,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 90,
            height: 80,
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _themeState.changeThemeData();
                debugPrint(_themeState.theme.toString());
                debugPrint(_themeState.isNight.toString());
              },
              child: const Text("Press Me"),
            ),
          ).onlyPadding(right: PaddingManager.commonHorizontal),
        ],
      ),
      body: Observer(
        name: "Center",
        builder: (_) {
          return Center(
            child: NavigatorRoutes().navPages.elementAt(rootStateManager.selectedIndexOfBottomNavigationBar),
          ).symmetricpadding(
            horizontal: PaddingManager.commonHorizontal,
            vertical: PaddingManager.commonVertical,
          );
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavigationBar(
        rootStateManager: rootStateManager,
      ).onlyPadding(
        left: PaddingManager.horizontalOfBottomNavigationBar,
        right: PaddingManager.horizontalOfBottomNavigationBar,
        bottom: PaddingManager.onlyBottomOfBottomNavigationBar,
        top: PaddingManager.onlyTopOfBottomNavigationBar,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

custom_bottom_navigation_bar.dart

```
class CustomBottomNavigationBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomBottomNavigationBar({
    Key? key,
    required this.rootStateManager,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final RootStateManager rootStateManager;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final selectedTheme = Theme.of(context);

    debugPrint("CustomBottomNavigationBar build");
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: ColorManager.darkSecondaryColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadiusManager.commonAllBorderRadius,
      ),
      child: Observer(builder: (_) {
        return GNav(
          activeColor: Theme.of(context).bottomNavigationBarTheme.selectedItemColor ?? Colors.pink,
          gap: 8,
          selectedIndex: rootStateManager.selectedIndexOfBottomNavigationBar,
          onTabChange: (index) {
            rootStateManager.setIndex(index);
            debugPrint(rootStateManager.selectedIndexOfBottomNavigationBar.toString());
          },
          tabs: const [
            GButton(
              icon: FontAwesomeIcons.house,
              text: TextManager.textHome,
            ),
            GButton(
              icon: FontAwesomeIcons.magnifyingGlass,
              text: TextManager.textSearch,
            ),
            GButton(
              icon: FontAwesomeIcons.locationCrosshairs,
              text: TextManager.textCurrent,
            ),
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of accessing Theme.of(context) directly in your widgets, you can consider using a Provider to manage the theme state and provide the theme to your widgets.

Comment: I guess I solved because of you :) There is no problem right now. Thanks for your command